# Facebook on Nexus 4 looks different than on Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-4, facebook, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 4 and Facebook looks like the picture on the left; while on my Nexus 5, it looks amazing, like the picture on the right (with fixed tap and native Android version):

[image: Ugly!]
[image: Wow!]

I tried re-installing the application and changing the device language with no luck. How can I get the Nexus 5 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). It is a part of Facebook test and targets few users. You cannot get that version, its Facebook who controls which user gets that and its basically random.

Answer (score 0):

It is the new Facebook app design. You don't choose to have it and it is not tied to a apk, but rather to your account. At a certain time, when you connect your account on a device and if your account has the new design, the app will switch itself to its design, but not instantaneously.

Comment: My facebook account is already using the latest design for weeks now. However, the facebook on my nexus looks the old one.